# spring + hibernate test service/dao insertion

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Is it possible to test insertion in insertion/updation in JUNIT?

my spring-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.isad" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix">
    <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
</property>
<property name="suffix">
    <value>.jsp</value>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" scope="singleton"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"></property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean id ="transactionManager" class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name = "sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

My testing configure:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:spring-servlet.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="transactionManager",defaultRollback=true)
@Transactional
public class TestItem {

@Autowired CategoryService    catManager;

@Test 
public void testItem() {
    //System.out.println("Begin Test");
    Category cat = new Category();
    cat.setType(CategoryType.BOOK);
    cat.setSubCategory("Business Book");
    cat.setDescription("One Thing");
    catManager.addCategory(cat);
}
}
```

And this is the stackstrace I got for running the above code:

```
Hibernate: insert into CATEGORY (DESCRIPTION, SUB_CAT, CAT_TYPE) values (?, ?, ?)
INFO | 2014-09-04 18:46:50,844 | TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java | 298 | Rolled back transaction after test execution for test context [DefaultTestContext@76f3da25 testClass = TestItem, testInstance = com.isad.test.dao.TestItem@376f026, testMethod = testItem@TestItem, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@75905090 testClass = TestItem, locations = '{classpath:spring-servlet.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]
INFO | 2014-09-04 18:46:50,847 | AbstractApplicationContext.java | 873 | Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@17372afb: startup date [Thu Sep 04 18:46:48 PDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
```

The problem I have is beside insertion and updation, my other methods such as deletions work just fine.

Comment: post the full stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test succeeded, but because this is a test and you have specified `defaultRollback=true`, when the test method ends, any changes that were made to your database were rolled back.

I'm going to assume that in your service you have a method that runs the equivalent of a `COUNT(*)` statement for this `Category` object
If you actually want to test if your insert succeeded, try the following code:

```
@Test
public void testInsertItem(){
    int countPreInsert = catManager.count();

    Category cat = new Category();
    cat.setType(CategoryType.BOOK);
    cat.setSubCategory("Business Book");
    cat.setDescription("One Thing");
    catManager.addCategory(cat);

    int countPostInsert = catManager.count();

    assertEqual("Exactly one record was not inserted in the database", 
        countPreInsert + 1, countPostInsert)
}
```

You don't have to do any cleanup because the `TransactionalTestExecutionListener` will automatically rollback your insert statement when the test concludes.

If you want to test an update, get a count pre and post update, and assert that they are both equal to ensure that Hibernate didn't insert or delete any records.

Happy testing!

Comment: For the update you could also use the embedded `JdbcTemplate` and do a `queryforMap` which gives you a key/value pair which you can then check with the asserted values. I always suggest to use another means (JDBC) to test your assumptions then the one you are using (JPA/Hibernate) it might be that the latter returns a correct result (due to caching) but that it hasn't been synchronized yet due to lacking tx setup.

Comment: Ahh, but Hibernate is smart enough to think of that. Whenever you call a count(*), Hibernate will flush the underlying session to the database, so that you don't get a stale read

Comment: In theory that is, if you start messing with flushmodes hibernate isn't that smart anymore...

Comment: That's why I never mess with the flush mode anyway. I just let Hibernate do it's thing.

Comment: +1 for the count(), I didn't think about this technique to test for the insertion. Thank you all for the instructions.